# Packaging a Gtk3 app for Windows for the Microsoft store

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2019, gtk3, vcpkg

Has anyone been successful at packaging a Gtk3 app for Windows for the Microsoft store?

I'm playing with this at the moment:

- Visual Studio 2019;
- Gtk3/Gtkmm distro obtained via vcpkg;
- C++ app;
- VS Application Packaging Project.

The application runs fine on its own. I then package it, and then run the MSIX bundle installer. When I then run the installed application, it starts *but*:

- an Access Denied error appears in a dialog box;
- the application appears with broken icons and incorrect colors (wrong or no theme).

I have tracked the error having to do with Gio-2.DLL where it attempts to spawn a child process, looks like something to do with creating a dbus server/session (??). I believe the child process (dbus server?) starts but then attempts to do something that is not permitted in the sandbox that Windows creates for the app.

Anyone?

Answer (score -1):

After some more investigation, I may have found a workaround. I'll post it here in case it helps anyone else. This workaround allows making a packaged Gtk3 application for Windows. A Windows packaged application runs in a sandbox of sorts, with heavily restricted access to resources outside the package.

First, the issue: during initialization, the version of Gio-2.DLL for Windows spawns a child process to serve as a DBus session daemon (I may get the terminology wrong here as I'm not that familiar with DBus). It does so only for the first instance. If one launches additional instances of applications that use Gio-2.DLL, the additional instances use the existing daemon from the first instance.

To launch the daemon, Gio-2.DLL calls CreateProcess() to fork a RUNDLL32.EXE child, with the full path to Gio-2.DLL (i.e. itself), and g_win32_run_session_bus() as the name of the function to call. It looks like RUNDLL32.EXE does launch successfully, since it is able to display the "RUNDLL" error dialog box. However it fails to make the requested function call into Gio-2.DLL. I gather that at least one of the system calls that RUNDLL32.EXE makes to load the DLL and call the requested function is prohibited when running in a packaged application.

At the moment, my workaround is this. Assume my application executable is called 'myapp.exe':

- the application package contains myapp.exe, all the necessary DLLs for Gtk3 and dependencies, and another executable 'dbus_daemon_launcher.exe';
- before entering the Gtk main loop, myapp.exe calls CreateProcess() to start dbus_daemon_launcher.exe;
- dbus_daemon_launcher.exe is also linked with Gio-2.DLL and makes a call to g_win32_run_session_bus() with the DLL;
- myapp.exe then proceeds to start the Gtk main loop. Since the Dbus daemon is then already running, Gio-2.DLL does not attempt to call RUNDLL32.EXE to launch it, which avoids the error.

This workaround has the advantage that it does not require making a custom version of Gio-2.DLL. Also, I'm using Gtk3: perhaps this issue has been addressed in the more recent Gtk4, and the workaround is unnecessary in this case.